# Getting the value of tag in razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need help : i need to know the value of for example `reception0` :

```
  <td >
    <label name="tag@(i)">@Model[1][i]._tag</label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" value="@Model[1][i]._client" name="client@(i)"/>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" value="@Model[1][i]._reception"  class="datepicker" name="reception@(i)"/>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" value="@Model[1][i]._cloture"  class="datepicker" name="cloture@(i)"/>
  </td>
  <td>
    @Html.ActionLink("enregistrer","Index", new {identificateur = Model[1][i].Id, Pages = "1", _reception ="reception"+""+i.ToString(), _cloture ="cloture"+""+i.ToString(), _client ="client"+""+i.ToString(), tag = "tag"+""+i.ToString()  })
  </td>
```

My problem is that i get `_reception = reception0` but i need the value of `reception0` not its name.

How can i fix my snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the value that you use for your input in the link helper

```
@Html.ActionLink( ... , _reception = Model[1][i]._reception, ... )
```

Comment: @Lamloumi - You are using it inside of your ActionLink already for the id. Specifically, what problem was caused by using `i`?

Comment: the problem is that i need to update for example `_reception` by the default value `Model[1][i]._reception` or by a new value puted in `<input type="text" value="@Model[1][i]._reception"  class="datepicker" name="reception@(i)"/>` if i changed the code as you said i will get always the old values

Comment: @Lamloumi - Razor renders information server side. It runs integrated into the http pipeline, specifically *during* the response. By the time the user is viewing the output of the information from razor, the content is static. In order to make any content dynamic while the user is interacting with it, you must use a client side approach with javascript.

Comment: Did you have a script suggestion to get values of each tags?